# Why is ContentCachingFilter being applied to all URLs instead of just /search even after specifying the same in urlPatterns?

Tags: java, spring-boot, filter

I have an application with multiple filters. I want ContentCachingFilter to be applied to all URLs having `/search`. Since there are other filters too so in the case of `/search` the `ContentCachingFilter` should be the first one to be applied. I tried providing the full URL as well in urlPatterns but still `doFilterInternal` from `ContentCachingFilter` is getting executed for all the URLS. Please find below the code

```
@Component     
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@WebFilter(filterName = "ContentCachingFilter", urlPatterns = "/search/*")
public class ContentCachingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override 
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        CachedBodyHttpServletRequest cachedBodyHttpServletRequest = 
                new CachedBodyHttpServletRequest(httpServletRequest);

        filterChain.doFilter(cachedBodyHttpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you inherited OncePerRequestFilter, you can override the shouldNotFilterMethod. Here is an example :

```
   @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return !request.getServletPath().startsWith("/search/");
    }
```